# Umbraco 8 how to line break in textareaEditor

Tags: umbraco8

When using Umbraco textarea, I need to have multiple lines with the `<br/>` tag

code is here

```
var subTitle = item.Value("sliderSubTitle");
```

and html code is

```
div>
                                @subTitle
                            </div>
```

but data comes in single line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check this?

```
<div>
@Html.Raw(subTitle.Replace("\n", "<br />"))    
</div>
```